# Buttons with mouse over and out function

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Check this url please http://x2t.com/262032
You can see how does facebook button work right side of navigation menu.

This code works with this button.

CSS

```
div.social-wrapper {
    float: right; 
    text-align: right; 
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin: 11px 15px 0px 0px; 
}
div.social-wrapper-text { 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
div.social-icon:first-child { 
    margin-left: 0px; 
}
div.social-icon { 
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 11px; 
    opacity: 0.55; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=55);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I need the code for two facebook buttons with mouse over and out function. 
On mouse over guest will see for example white FB button and on mouse over black one.

How to do this?

Comment: this is purely css question no php or wordpress skill required

Answer (score 1):

```
<button class="class_of_button">    like us on facebook </button>
.class_of_button {
    background: url('source of fb image');
    }

    .class_of_button:hover {
    background: url('source of black fb image'); 
    }
```

Comment: Where can I put this code? Must I change old css code shown above with this code or...?

Comment: then this code could help you as this is not the fully baked cake to eat. you have to improvise it according to your needs.

Comment: I understand but I don't know where to put it))

Comment: in the same file form where you copied code snippet for you question,

Comment: So, I put it in my theme's style.css below with no results. Then I change this code div.social-icon { 
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 11px; 
    opacity: 0.55; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=55);
    cursor: pointer;
} but with no results again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40830/discussion-between-viktor-saneev-and-pr1nc3)

Answer (score 0):

Here my personal solution for this:
HTML:

```
<div class="social-icon">
<a href="CHANGE THIS LINK TO YOUR ONE">
        <img src="MOUSE_OFF.jpg"></img>
        <img src="MOUSE_ON.jpg"></img>
</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.social-icon
{
    width: 600px; /* Width of IMG, TO BE CHANGED *
    height: 800px; /* Height of IMG, TO BE CHANGED *
}

div.social-icon img:nth-child(2)
{
    display: none;
}

div.social-icon img:first-child
{ 
    display: block;
}

div.social-icon:hover img:nth-child(2)
{ 
    display: block;
}

div.social-icon:hover img:first-child
{ 
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Just put the CSS into the 
and the html where you would have placed your button.
And don't forget to change the mentioned values in the css and html.

And yes: You have to create the images yourself, so show yourself some Paint skillz~

Comment: Thanks but I'm too poor in css and php :(